# Variable as a variable

Tags: php

Im a New programmer I new a few help, I have a code where I need to call many different variables like this:

```
$Variable1="red"
$Variable2="blue"
$Variable3="yellow"
```

How can I call my variable as a variable like this:

```
$number = 1;
$color=$variable.$number;
```

Or how can u do that, thank you.

Comment: Sounds like what you really need is an array. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Search for what you ask for.. downvoted because this was not done. Although better would be to use a ("array") collection.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `array`

```
$variables = array(0, 'red', 'blue', 'yellow');
$number = 1;
$color = $variables[$number];
echo $color;
```

Using as **@frymaster**'s answer:

```
$Variable1="red";
$Variable2="blue";
$Variable3="yellow";

$number = 2;

$colour = "Variable{$number}";
print $$colour;
```

Or using `eval()` function - not recommend to use

```
$variable1 = 'red';
$variable2 = 'blue';
$variable3 = 'yellow';
$number = 1;
eval("echo $variable" . $number . ";");
```

Answer (score 0):

thi tran's answer is, really, the best solution. if you're going to use numbers to differentiate elements of data in a set... well, that's what the array was  designed to do!

having said that, you can make a 'variable variable' and use that, if you *really* want to. but the array is a smarter choice.

here's the variable variable $colour

```
<?php

$Variable1="red";
$Variable2="blue";
$Variable3="yellow";

$number = 2;

$colour = "Variable{$number}";
print $$colour;
```

Comment: yes, i forget this way, i have just edited my answer, thanks

Comment: Yes, but i would not recommend using such code, years ago I ran across this and when WtH, thought it was a typo.  To me code should be clear and concise as to its purpose.  Variable Variables, while valid are best left in the dustbin of PHP4 if you ask me.

Comment: oh, i fully agree! variable variables are just asking for trouble imho. again, thi tran's original suggestion to use variables is far and away the best approach. i only added this because it explicitly answered the op's question.